# Integral over Julia Set (Is my math correct?)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, fractals, fractal-analysis

So I was answering [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829513/can-a-julia-set-fractal-be-described-in-a-closed-form) question about whether or not the Julia Set was self-similar in a known way. Of course it is, and that got me thinking. Even though the self similarity is nonlinear, what if you could exploit it to integrate over a normalized haussdorf...so I started small, I just wanted to see if I could get,

$$(1) \quad \int_J z \ \mu(dz)$$

The Julia Set, $J$, is the attractor of the dynamical system (IFS),

[image]

$$(2) \quad F \rightarrow w_1(F) \cup w_2(F)$$
$$w_1(z)=\sqrt{z+\lambda} \ , \quad w_1(z)=-\sqrt{z+\lambda}$$

So, the integral can be rewritten as,

$$(3) \quad \int_J z \ \mu(dz)=\int_{w_1(J)} z \ \mu(dz)+\int_{w_2(J)} z \ \mu(dz)$$

The first an second integrals on the right can be written after the substitutions $z \rightarrow w_1(z)$ and $z \rightarrow w_2(t)$ as,

$$(4) \quad \int_J z \ \mu(dz)=\int_{J} \sqrt{z+\lambda} \ \mu \left(\cfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z+\lambda}} \right)+\int_{J} -\sqrt{z+\lambda} \ \mu \left(-\cfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z+\lambda}} \right)=0$$

Which is rather boring. So, next I tried,

$$(5) \quad \int_J z^2 \ \mu(dz)$$

After applying the self-similarity, and applying a change of variables,  I get,

$$(6) \quad \int_J z^2 \ \mu(dz)=\int_J z+\lambda \ \mu \left(\cfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z+\lambda}} \right)+\int_J z+\lambda \ \mu \left(-\cfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z+\lambda}} \right)$$

I remember the value of $(1)$ so combining the integral into one with that in it is a good choice. I also remember that the negative sign inside the measure is irrelevant, so I get,

$$(7) \quad \int_J z^2 \ \mu(dz)=2 \int_J z+\mu \left(\cfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z+\lambda}} \right)+2 \lambda \int_J \mu \left(\cfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z+\lambda}} \right)=2 \lambda \int_J \mu \left(\cfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z+\lambda}} \right)$$

Then changing variables back using $z \rightarrow w^{-1}_1(z)$, I get,

$$(8) \quad \int_J z^2 \ \mu(dz)=2 \lambda \int_{w_1(J)} \mu \left( dz \right)=\lambda$$

So my result for $(5)$ is,

$$(9) \quad \int_J z^2 \ \mu(dz)=\lambda$$

Is this correct? If not, what's the correct way? Anyone see any tricks I could've used to speed this up?

Comment: If you haven't seen it before, you might be interested in this paper: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/AMM/evaluatingintegrals.pdf .

Comment: @anomaly Yes, I have. Good introduction, sadly nothing more advanced on the topic.